# How can fixe the probel of saving gganime file that is related to using the old API?

Tags: ggplot2, gganimate

My code is following:

```
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world, size = .1) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = SupDem), data = plotdata) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma") +
  ggtitle("Democratic Support - {closest_state}") +
  transition_states(Year)

anim_save("SupforDemAnim.gif", p)
```

The error:

Error: It appears that you are trying to use the old API, which has been deprecated.
Please update your code to the new API or install the old version of gganimate
from https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/releases/tag/v0.1.1